# jQuery Select Dynamically Content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a page which contain dynamic content.

```
<div id="content-1">
    <div id="subcontent-1"></div>
    <i id="delete-1"></i>
</div>
.
.
.
<div id="content-10">
    <div id="subcontent-10"></div>
    <i id="delete-10"></i>
</div>
```

How to select dynamic content with jQuery selectors and how to understand which content will be deleted I'm not sure and confused.

Need to understand which delete for  clicked by user.

Comment: You want to remove content on delete click?

Comment: yes, normally I can do it with static content. But this time I am not sure which selector will be used? I mean which delete clicked

Comment: You can use `$(this)` of the clicked element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your markup, it will be easier to select elements if you can add a class to them like

```
<div id="content-1" class="content">
    <div id="subcontent-1"></div>
    <i id="delete-1" class="delete">i</i>
</div>
```

then use the class selector to register the event handlers

```
$(document).on('click', '.content .delete', function(){
    $(this).closest('.content').remove();
})
```

- [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)